# flex 4 pause execution temporarily

Tags: flex4, httprequest

I am building a database dependent application using Flex-4. I would like the application to pause execution till i receive a reply from my DB (using PHP-SQL request). Flex, in its execution, even if you call for a user input required Alert/Pop-Up, displays the Alert and continues further execution without pausing for a user input.

One work around was to send the data request in one function and check the arrival of the requested data in another (maybe use the result event as a trigger). But I would like to have a pause-continue functionality.

Please assist.

Thanks and Regards,

Rahul

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by **pausing** the application. From your question, it seems as though you want to prevent any input from the user. This is usually done by disabling all the user controls till you receive the response from the server. Instead of doing that for each control, you can directly disable the panel in which all these controls are placed.

Answer (score 0):

Send a callback to your function that is executing the DB code.